# 'Parameter count mismatch' Error when trying to insert List<dynamic> to Excel using closedXml InsertData

Tags: excel, export, .net-6.0, closedxml, dynamic-linq

I am trying to export dynamic list items to excel using ClosedXML. The goal is to allow end user to select the columns to be exported. Since the columns are dynamic, I use.ToDynamicListAsync() of System.Linq.Dynamic.Core name space.
The problem is excel export works fine if I create anonymous object but throws error when I directly pass the select query as shown below. I directly pass the select cols bcoz the cols will be known only at runtime.

**Below is the code snapshot for clarity**

```cs
            using ClosedXML.Excel;
            using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;

            var filter = "MeetingNo = 85";
            var query = context.PrmProjects.AsNoTracking().Where(filter);

            var items = await query.Select(x => new
            {
                x.OrganizationId,
                x.ProjectNo,
                x.MeetingNo,
                x.Name
            }).ToDynamicListAsync();
            using var wb = new XLWorkbook();
            var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add();
            ws.Cell(3, 1).InsertData(items); /// WORKS FINE


            var selectQuery = $"new(OrganizationId,ProjectNo,MeetingNo,Name)";
            var items1 = await query.Select(selectQuery).ToDynamicListAsync();
            using var wb2 = new XLWorkbook();
            var ws2 = wb2.Worksheets.Add();
            ws2.Cell(3, 1).InsertData(items1); /// THROW ERROR 'Parameter count mismatch'
```

`

In the above sample code InsertData with the list 'items' works fine but 'items1' throws an error 'Parameter count mismatch'

**Screenshot of List 'items', working fine**:
[image]

**Screenshot of List 'items1', throw error**:[image]

**Error screenshot:**
**[image]**

Can any one please help me. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Could it be because `MeetingNo` can be null?

Comment: it is not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause for this error is that System.Linq.Dynamic.Core creates a new dynamic type based on [DynamicClass](https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/blob/master/src/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/DynamicClass.cs) which does also have an indexer:

```cs
public object? this[string name]
{
    get
    {
        //
    }

    set
    {
        //
    }
}
```

The ClosedXml calls [GetProperties(...)](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/blob/develop/ClosedXML/Excel/InsertData/ObjectReader.cs#L31) in the `ObjectReader.cs` class and this `GetProperties` does return 5 entries:

- OrganizationId
- ProjectNo
- MeetingNo
- Name
- **Index** --> This is the indexer defined on the DynamicClass which is not really a normal property.

So actually ClosedXML should be [fixed](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/1904) to exclude indexer methods.
Example:

```cs
int parameters = propertyInfo.GetIndexParameters().Length;
if (parameters > 0)
{
    // The property is an indexer, skip this.
    continue;
}
```